# Python package installation via yum

Tags: python, security, pip, centos7, yum

What could be the difference of installing python packages via `yum` vs. via `pip`on `Centos` in terms of security? Is it even possible to install a python package only via `yum`?

Comment: In terms of security? What kind of security? And what does this have to do with programming? are you sure this is on-topic here?

Answer (score 0):

`yum` can be used to install Python on CentOS.

`pip` is used to install Python libraries (packages). Not Python itself.

No "security" issue. But with `yum` you could overwrite your native Python installation, which can be a problem.

Instead of that, it is recommended to use [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/).

Comment: So the security guy at work says that with `pip` you copy pre-installed files which is not the case with `yum`. I'm pretty clueless what he is talking about and if this is any true!